# Https and 443 port nextjs

Tags: reactjs, https, port, next.js

**Hello, I want to run my nextjs project on https and 443 port, but I couldn't. Is there anyone who can help with this issue?**

Comment: Can you show us your configs and tell us what you tried yet?

Comment: Actually I couldn't find anything to try much but I tried $ env: HTTPS = "true" and $ env: PORT = 443 commands like react but they didn't work in my nextjs project

Answer (score 1):

Usage

```
Install package:

    `npm install redirect-ssl`

    Require and use redirect-ssl. Make sure to use this middlware as the first in your middleware chain (if using express see middleware chain:

    import redirectSSL from 'redirect-ssl'

// or
const redirectSSL = require('redirect-ssl')

    enter code here

// Add middleware
app.use(redirectSSL)

// Using custom options

app.use(redirectSSL.create({ redirectPort: 8443 }))
Disable for non-production or localhost

If you want to disable on localhost, use the exclude option:

app.use(redirectSSL.create({
   exclude: ['localhost']
}))
Only enable in production environments:

app.use(redirectSSL.create({
  enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
}))

Default: 443
Redirect users to this port for HTTPS. (:443 is omitted from URL as is default for https:// schema)
```

---

```
Using with Nuxt.js
Add the redirect-ssl to the serverMiddleware array within in the nuxt.config.js file is the preferred usage:

import redirectSSL from 'redirectSSL'

export default {
  serverMiddleware: [
    redirectSSL.create({
      enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
     }),
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you be more clear on your answer? Like give more instruction on what needs to be done instead of just copying and pasting the code